# How to remove builds and testers from the app you want transferred in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-transfer

One of my Apple developer account is expiring, and I am trying to transfer my existing app to a newly registered account.

When I pressed the "Transfer App" button, it listed a set of criteria that my app has to meet, one of the pending criteria is ***"You must remove all builds and testers from the app you want transferred and clear each information field below Test Information."***

However, I navigate through the iTunes Connect pages back and forth, and couldn't find the options to "remove all the builds" or "remove testers". Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only options I see for removing testers/builds come up under TestFlight. Try there? There's an edit button on the testers row. [image]

Comment: I can confirm this. Had to do it myself a couple of days ago when transferring an app.

Comment: It can also take a few minutes after you clear out TestFlight before App Store Connect recognizes this fact, and allows you to continue the transfer process.

Comment: I have over 200 testers (had a public tester link). I need to select over 200 checkboxes? :/

Answer (score 22):

These are all the things you have to do in order to get green on the last checkbox:

Go to Test Flight, then

- **Expire all builds:**

Click on the build number next to the icon, then click the 'Expire build' button at the top right, do this for every build:

[image]

- **Delete all testers**
- **Select 'not available for testing' for internal and external testing (if applicable)**
- **Clear all fields from 'Test Information' for every language (or remove languages):**

[image]

Comment: Ridiculous. How is expiring every single build by hand even acceptable? What if I have hundreds of builds? How is everyone content with this?

Comment: Also under **Sign-In Information** make sure you clear out User Name and Password and not just uncheck **Sign-in required**.

Comment: Jamie's correct.  Another note that this single checkbox will prevent the green check. 
 I also noticed a bug where Sign-In Information stays checked even though you save it unchecked. To fix this, enter some text in Beta App Description, uncheck Sign-in required, and Save. Then Delete the text and uncheck sign in required.

Comment: The 'expire all builds' step is what I missed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had a space in once of the fields that prevented the transfer. Make sure you clear all input boxes

Comment: @xip It does seem ridiculous to me too. Thankfully, all builds will automatically expire after a certain time, so even though I had 400+ builds on the app I wanted to transfer, I only needed to manually Expire about 12 of them because the rest were old enough they had auto-expired.

Answer (score 13):

This is How I solved the problems.

- Make all build staus are expired.
- Deleted all crashes & screenshots.
- Delete all tester.
- Delete all internal & external testing.
- **Clear all test information.**

The last point is very important.
Make sure all fields are empty(double-check if blank space)

As there are some previous values like the first name, last name then I could not save it as empty, there is a validation that occurred to prevent me to clear the fields.

**How to solve this**:

Like default language is selected in English. I inserted a
blank space into all fields.

Then I added another language like Arabic. Tap the save button. Then all field will clear and be saved.

Then you will find the transfer is active.

Answer (score 10):

D. Pratt's comment about `It can also take a few minutes after you clear out TestFlight before App Store Connect recognizes this fact` is what I found to be the issue. Took about 10 minutes for it to kick in on Apple's side before it realized my TestFlight info was clear.

Patience is the key.

Answer (score 8):

For me, even tho i deleted everything, i still had the error.

Surprisingly , after i ADDED (it was not available before) a secondary language in the Test Information in TestFlight tab, then delete the language, it magically fixed itself.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, and it's 2024, Apple still didn't fix this ridiculous issue :D

Answer (score 2):

Just did an app transfer right now.

- Delete testing groups. Which is pretty easy.
- Under `TestFlight/general information`, You will see all testers. If there are any in that list remove them. Once you remove them those users will go to deleted users section. That's all right. Leave them there.
- Under `TestFlight/general information`, go to the `test information` section from the left side panel and clear all the fields, and save. Make sure there is no single whitespace left as well.
- You have to expire **Not expired** builds. As of today, TestFlight builds which are older than 90 days get expired automatically. So no need to expire all of the uploaded builds.

Then you are good to go ahead with the app transfer. Cheers!

#### Further help

You then need to find the following

##### Recipient's Account Holder Apple ID

1. Go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage
2. Click in the middle under Apple ID

##### Team ID

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account
2. Login -> Account (If you aren't logge in yet)
3. Scroll down to `Team ID` (Or search with the google Search)

Comment: So by all fields he means all fields, like First name and such. Take me a while to find it '^^